# iOS 7 App Crashes (crash log included) when entering foreground (after being in background for a while)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, crash

I am going to paste my crash log for  the app. I have a feeling it has something to do with the UIWebView getting overloaded with data while in the background (web sockets), but I may be wrong so I wanted to see if anyone here would be willing to analyze my crash log and see what's going on.

SYMBOLIZED Log w/ Breakpoints: http://pastebin.com/q63QvURY

Comment: Please [symbolize your crash report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports), the way it is now is useless.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gdHLp3UC Is this properly symbolized? I sure hope so. :)

Comment: I suggest you to enable all exception breakpoints to determine the exact error row: See image below ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1vrz6.png)

Comment: i have the new log with the all exception breakpoints added. http://pastebin.com/q63QvURY (did I do this right?)

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is continuing after your UIWebView's delegate is deallocated.  The crash happens because the connection is trying to update an object which has been deallocated.

From the [UIWebView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate):

> **Important**: Before releasing an instance of `UIWebView` for which you have set a delegate, you must first set its delegate property to `nil`. This can be done, for example, in your dealloc method.

For example:

```
- (void) dealloc {
    self.myWebview.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: If I release the instance of the UIWebView in the dealloc - does that mean I have to connect it again with self.myWebView.delagate = self? or something along those lines?

Comment: `self.myWebView.delegate = self` is how you would set the delegate to `self` programmatically.  Presumably you're already doing that in `init`, `viewDidLoad`, or in your XIB/Storyboard file.